Call inject() inside a property decorator
I want to create a decorator that injects and uses a service
function MyDecorator(){
  return function(target: any, prop: string){
    // error: inject() must be called from an injection context
    let service = inject(MyService);

    // trying to call it inside the constructor
    // but it seems that the constructor already called
    let constructor = target.constructor;
    target.constructor = function(...args: any[]){
        constructor.apply(this, args);
        service = inject(MyService)
   }

   // trying to call it inside ngOnInit
   // will fail according to the docs because it is too late
   // https://angular.dev/errors/NG0203

}
}

using runInInjectionContext() also impossible because it needs something to be injected
return function(target: any, prop: string){
   // inject environmentInjector somehow

    runInInjectionContext(this.environmentInjector, () => {
      service = inject(MyService);
    });

}

Usage:
@Component(...)
class MyComp{
  @Mydecorator() myProp: string
}

I don't want the consumer of this decorator to make any special changes to his component.
update:
solved initially by using AppInjector
export let AppInjector: Injector;

@Component(...)
export class AppComponent{
   constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    AppInjector = this.injector;
  }
}

though it still gives an error ASSERTION ERROR: Unexpected state: hydrating an <ng-container>, but no hydration info is available. [Expected=> number === object <=Actual], but till now I can inject the service.

Using runInInjectionContext is what you need, you were already there, just create an Injector and pass it to the function like this:
function MyDecorator() {
  return function (target: any, prop: string) {
    const injector = Injector.create({ providers: [MyService] }); //Creates the injector, provide the services that you need
    runInInjectionContext(injector, () => {
      const service = inject(MyService);
      Object.defineProperty(target, prop, {
        get: function () {
          return service;
        },
      });
    });
  };
}

That is it, if you want to improve the decorator just use some reflect-metadata.
Update tsconfig
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  }
}

Update the decorator to inject any type:
function MyDecorator() {
  return function (target: any, prop: string) {
    const injector = Injector.create({ providers: [MyService] });
    const type = Reflect.getMetadata('design:type', target, prop);
    runInInjectionContext(injector, () => {
      const service = inject(type); //now can inject any provided service
      Object.defineProperty(target, prop, {
        get: function () {
          return service;
        },
      });
    });
  };
}

This is the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qbjz1j?file=src%2Fmain.ts
UPDATE: The following is a nasty solution, but can work to inject dependencies in NodeInjector, if your services are provided at root, you only need the APP_INITIALIZER implementation.
The following code target.constructor.ɵcmp.providersResolver can be avoided if your services are provided at root.
function MyDecorator() {
  return function (target: any, prop: string) {
    const type = Reflect.getMetadata('design:type', target, prop);
    Object.defineProperty(target, prop, {
      get: function () {
        const injector: Injector = Reflect.getMetadata(
          InjectorSymbol,
          InjectorEnvironment
        );
        let service = null;
        try {
          //Nasty Solution to access the providers of the NodeInjector.
          //Implements a catch error, we do not neet to execute the function again, just get the providers
          target.constructor.ɵcmp.providersResolver(
            target.constructor.ɵcmp,
            (providers: any[]) => {
              service = Injector.create({ providers, parent: injector }).get(
                type
              );
              return providers;
            }
          );
        } catch (_) {}
        return service;
      },
    });
  };
}

We use this for the metadata.
const InjectorSymbol = Symbol('InjectorSymbol');
class InjectorEnvironment {}

The following code registers the environment injector in the metadata, so the property decorator can access to it.
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      deps: [Injector],
      multi: true,
      useFactory: (injector: Injector) => {
        return () => {
          Reflect.defineMetadata(InjectorSymbol, injector, InjectorEnvironment);
          return Promise.resolve();
        };
      },
    },
  ],
});


I tried it to inject HttpClient but got NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpHandler! that is mean that Injector.create() doesn't resolve the dependency tree of the service being injected

If you want to access to the injector tree, then there is no way to do it, you would need another approach, for example trying to decorate the class component but you cannot! angular does not allow/support custom decorators on angular decorated classes. Im not saying that is impossible, there are ways to get the injector but it would go against to what you want to achieve.

@Sherifeldeeb updated the code, is not good but could work, although is not recommended, the example is in stackblitz.

really big thanks for your great effort @Oscar Ludick
